# Proving a property by using the spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).

> I want to show  by using the spectral theorem that: for any $x\in F$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with 
>   $$M^{1/2}x=\lim_{n\to \infty} Mx_n\;.$$

Comment: $dE_{\lambda }$ is supported by $\sigma (M)$ which is a subset of $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binomial expansion. Suppose that $0 \le M \le I$, which you can do by scaling $M$ by a positive constant, if necessary. Then the unique positive square root of $M$ is given by the binomial expansion,
$$
         M^{1/2} = (I-(I-M))^{1/2}=I-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(I-M)^n,
$$
where $c_n$ are positive constants such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n=1$. You can use that to show that the range of $M$ is dense in the range of $M^{1/2}$.

Using the spectral theorem, and assuming $L$ is an upper bound for the spectrum of $M$,
$$
    M\int_{1/n}^{L}\lambda^{-1/2}dE(\lambda)x= \int_{1/n}^{L}\lambda^{1/2}dE(\lambda)x.
$$

So $x_n=\int_{1/n}^{L}\lambda^{-1/2}dE(\lambda)x$ is such that $Mx_n\rightarrow M^{1/2}x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which proves that the range of $M$ is dense in the range of $M^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Schüler : I added another paragraph using the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: @Schüler : I left $x$ out! Fixed.

Comment: Please how can I use $$
         M^{1/2} = (I-(I-M))^{1/2}=I-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(I-M)^n,
$$ to show the density? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler : You can use the fact that I gave you: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n = 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your idea very well. I hope that you add this in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler $M^{1/2} x= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} x-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(I-M)^n x$ and $x-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n x =0$, which leads to $x$ being in the closure of the range of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of the claim on page 5. Given
$M\geq0$ in $\mathcal{H}$, there is an associated Hilbert space
$\mathbf{R}(M^{1/2})$, with the inner product 
\begin{align*}
\left\langle x,y\right\rangle _{M} & :=\left\langle x,My\right\rangle 
\end{align*}
modulo elements s.t. $\left\langle x,Mx\right\rangle =0$.

Claim: The range of $M$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}\left(M^{1/2}\right)$,
i.e., 
\begin{align*}
\left[\left\langle Mx,y\right\rangle _{M}=0,\;\forall x\in\mathcal{H}\right] & \Longrightarrow y=0\in\mathbf{R}(M^{1/2}).
\end{align*}
This is true, since $\left\langle Mx,y\right\rangle _{M}=0$, $\forall x\in\mathcal{H}$
iff $\left\langle x,M^{2}y\right\rangle =0$, $\forall x\in\mathcal{H}$
iff $M^{2}y=0$ in $\mathcal{H}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\left\langle y,My\right\rangle  & \leq\left\Vert y\right\Vert ^{2}\left\langle y,M^{2}y\right\rangle =0,
\end{align*}
i.e., $y$ is the zero vector in $\mathbf{R}(M^{1/2})$.

Comment: Is it incorrect that for any $x\in F$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with
$$M^{1/2}x=\lim_{n\to \infty} Mx_n\;?$$

Comment: Yes. Since $ker\left(M\right)=ker\left(M^{1/2}\right)$, so $\overline{ran\left(M\right)}=\overline{ran(M^{1/2})}$.
(Note, $Mx=0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\left\Vert M^{1/2}x\right\Vert ^{2}=\left\langle x,Mx\right\rangle =0$,
so $M^{1/2}x=0$.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that answer. All I'm saying is that ''It is worth noting that R(A) is dense in R(A1/2)'' is not what the cited paper meant on page 5.